# Server not booting after 16.04 upgrade (not pinging)

Tags: boot, server, 16.04, rescue-mode

Yesterday I upgraded my server to 16.04, all fine and when I rebooted the server rebooted to rescue.

I fixed package conflicts with `apt-get autoremove` and `apt-get upgrade` etc...  I also tried to repair grub mounting my hd in /mnt and working with chroot, it seems all ok.

When I try to reboot from hard drive (I've a administration panel because i'm on OVH server), the server ping for 1 second.  After a few minutes I received this e-mail from OVH support:

> The server has started (login is requested on the screen)  but inaccessible by the network (not pinging). A restart on the OVH Kernel ('netboot') does not correct the problem.

After that the server rebooted in rescue mode from OVH.
Any ideas?

Service Output

```
● network.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone with the same problem I found the solution in this log file 
**/mnt/var/log/dmesg** (server boot log) and almost at the end I found that the disk was mounted in readonly during boot (IDK Why).

So fixed with a fsck and a touch /forcefsck and rebooted from HD.

All working